# How to get Friend's location(Longitude and latitude)?

Tags: android, android-widget, geolocation, gps, android-manifest

I have an application which needs friend's location(lon & lat) using their mobile numbers.Can anyone give me some idea how to do that ?

Comment: mobile nos means mobile numbers ?

Comment: yeah,I have corrected it in question as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can never get someone elses location simply from the mobile number, that is like stalking.

Google provide a service called [Latitude](http://www.google.co.uk/latitude) which is a much better, legal way of doing this.

---

Otherwise, if the two uses have the same application, they should push their location (obtained from the Cell ID or GPS) to a Web Server (which you will handle). You can then exchange the location coordinates using your web-service. For reference, have a look at the Table 1 [over here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms980225.aspx#v35go_topic2)

---

Code to detect SMS messages

```
public class IncomingSmsCapture extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();       
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String data = "";           
if (bundle != null)
{
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];           
    for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);               
    String sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();      
    data = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString(); 
    // parse the data and extract the location, then convert to an Address using the GeoCoder. 
}    }   }   }
```

Comment: yes,Google Latitude is very good but I need to find friend's location in my application.Can you explain that second method (which needs a web server) ?

Comment: [Google Latitude has api's](http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/v1/getting_started.html) which you can use in your application. For the web-server: I've updated with an existing reference.

Comment: @Reno : If android sdk has google latitude api's then why would I need a web server because google latitude is itself capable of locating the friend.What is the role of web server then ? I have one more question, can we do it like sms for eg, when a user wants to locate his friend then he sends a sms containing his own loaction to that friend and when his friend accepts that he will send his location to that friend.So both of them will have location of each other.Is it feasible to do so? If yes have you come across some code or documentation on internet ?

Comment: That was an alternate option given to you, Also updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use  CellID.A CellID is a number which is associated with a specific cell (the radio tower to which your handset is connected). In most cases, this is the closest tower to your location. So by knowing the location of this tower, then you can know approximately where the handset is.

For better Idea Take a look at here

[Adding location to a non GPS phone: introducing CellID](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/adding-location-a-non-gps-phone-introducing-cellid)

Now if you know your friends cellId then you can know their location.Another way

[Developing Location Based Services: Introducing the Location API for J2ME](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/developing-location-based-services-introducing-location-api-j2me)

Comment: But android comes with gps technology so can't we have any gps based technology which can help me because cell id will give location of nearest tower instead of actual location so if two friends come in range of same tower their location will be same but in actual this is not the case.So please suggest some other technology ?

Comment: Well In J2ME  I use The Location API .The Location API for J2ME specification defines an optional package, javax.microedition.location, that enables developers to write wireless location-based applications and services for resource-limited devices like mobile phones, and can be implemented with any common location method.  http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/location/